# Opening solution using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been working on this little mobile app for android using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017.

When opening the solution with the laptop that I used to develop the app works like a charm. Then I zip the entire folder over the solution.

```
../myFolder/
    app1/                     //here is all the code
    app1.sln                  //solution file

 myFolder.zip
```

Transfer the `zip` file to other laptop/PC through usb, email and online repository, even extensions like `rar`, `7zp` and `tar`. I simply can not load the solution from other Visual Studio but the one where I created/developed the application originally.

[image: load screen from vs]

Hours passing with this screen then VS is not responding and after that, it simply crashes/closes with no error message.

In the other hand, I can open any solution created from any other PC in my laptop without issues. After saving, I haven't found the pattern yet, but some solutions can't be opened from the original PC which creates them nor others.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza thanks a lot, could you post it as a solution so I can mark it correct? Also, I'm new with Xamarin, could you explain me a little more about this?

Comment: Take a look if it's clear enough for you. I'm glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be using an older version of Visual Studio on the PC you've facing the issue. [I've faced that too](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/302179).

It was a known bug ([reported here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58458) and [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60080)) already fixed on newer versions.

The workaround is to close VS, delete the folder `vs` created in the same directory of your solution and try to reopen it.

To avoid other problems on compiling or running your app after that, I recommend you also to delete all `bin` and `obj` folders from your project's folders, clean and rebuild the solution.

It's safer keep all your development environments updated in software wise to avoid this kind of trouble.

I hope it helps.