# Xamarin.Forms Tasks don't match targets

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was working fine with in my project ,the once I updated my Xamrain.Forms to 3.0, all of a sudden I got this error  : [image]

Has anyone come across this issue? I'm kinda lost here, thanks .

Comment: Have you checked what the message is saying? All projects are using the same Xamarin.Forms version?

Comment: If in fact you have updated **all** the projects to include Forms' 3.0, perform a **Clean All** and try to build it again

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza it should be right ? all what I did is updating the Xamarin.Forms . Sorry me I'm quite new to this whole thing

Comment: I faced some updating issues with xamarin.forms too. Sometimes it isn't a trivial job, indeed. If all your projects are using the same XF version, [try this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50224100/8093394). If it still doesn't work, we'll have to take a deep look in your build output data.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that message a few times when upgrading and downgrading from XF 3.0. If all your projects actually are on the same version usually closing the solution, reopening, and rebuilding the whole thing fixed it for me. Worse case I've occasionally seen duplicate XF references in a .csproj, which you'd have to check and look at manually to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please ensure that all projects reference the same version of
>   Xamarin.Forms

So make sure that the statement above is correct, clean your solution and just in case restart the Visual Studio after that.

EDIT:
It seems to be a quite popular issue after upgrading to Xamarin Forms 3.0, if the steps above didn't resolve it please consider:

- Delete all `/bin`, `/obj` and `/packages` folders within the solution
- Check `csproj` files for duplicated Xamarin Forms references
- Re-add Xamarin Forms NuGet packages

Comment: the statement is correct + I cleaned and resorted VS , still the same

Comment: I would recommend to manually delete /bin, /obj and /packages directories. Then restore NuGet packages and rebuild.

Comment: Check the csproj files, sometimes they may contain imports of older XF. Another idea is to completely remove XF and re-add to all the projects.

Answer (score 4):

Issue with my project was that, Project.Android and Project.iOS's Nu Get packages Xamarin.Forms's versions were different, so I had to update all Xamarin.Forms library in each project to the same version.

Clean, Build and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

this should help:

You need to click RMB on each (Droid, IOS, UWP)-project -> Nuget -> and then update Xamarin Forms for every project to the same version, even "solution".

Answer (score 0):

I would not call it a solution, but uninstalling the app from the device prior to every build was the only way forward I have found.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above to no avail.
What helped me was the following:

1. Close Visual Studio (for mac in my case)
2. `nuget locals all -list`
3. Delete all nuget cache folders
4. Restart visual studio and try again.