# Xamarin Forms on TeamCity: Xamarin.Forms tasks do not match targets

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, teamcity

I am building a Xamarin Forms solution (containing an iOS library, an Android library and a .NET Standard library) in TeamCity.

I have just upgraded to Xamarin Forms 3.1.0.583944. The project builds without any problem locally, but on my TeamCity build server (Windows Server 2016), I'm consistently getting the following error:

> C:\BuildAgent\work\f12265fda07473c1\src\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.583944\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets(44,
>   3): error XF002: Xamarin.Forms tasks do not match targets. Please
>   ensure that all projects reference the same version of Xamarin.Forms,
>   and if the error persists, please restart the IDE.

I have tried downgrading Xamarin Forms, and rebooting the build agent. Neither of these has succeeded.

**UPDATE**: There is a new error:

> C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.0.0.561731\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets(44, 3): error XF002: Xamarin.Forms tasks do not match targets. Please ensure that all projects reference the same version of Xamarin.Forms, and if the error persists, please restart the IDE.

For some reason, the agent is looking for Version 3.0.0.561731. But that is no longer anywhere in the project. I had deleted the entire `C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.0.0.561731` folder, but it has come back.

**ADDENDUM**: I notice that every time I upgrade Xamarin.Forms to this version via NuGet, it fails to uninstall the old package, and I have to restart Visual Studio to complete the process. This happens without fail. I am fairly sure this is connected to the breaking build, but that is more due to speculation and experience than concrete analysis.

Comment: Like the message says: be sure all projects have the same version of Xamarin.Forms intalled. It might also be worth it to clean any caches that might be going on on the build agent.

Comment: I've checked in the packages folder on the build agent. There is only one version.

Comment: Caches from previous builds?

Comment: Still no luck. Cleared the caches via Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager -> Clear all Nuget caches

Comment: I RDPed onto the build agent, opened Visual Studio, and built the project. It built without any errors. And yet the automated build is still failing with the same message.

Comment: I also changed the build targets from "Rebuild" to "Clean Rebuild", but that didn't work either.

Comment: Strange. Sounds like everything should be cleaned now. Just for sanity, could you check in the build folder on the agent and delete all bin and obj folders for each of the projects manually for once?

Comment: I tried that, but couldn't find any bin or obj folders in the build folder. I've got a meeting now, but I'll get back to this and update accordingly. I'm blocked on this, so it's not really an option not to solve it.

Comment: Seems there are more issues with this: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1537 you could tweak the targets file yourself to be able to go ahead, but not a lasting solution of course. There is also a possible cause in your csproj file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239480/xamarin-forms-tasks-dont-match-targets?rq=1

Comment: Import statements might also be found in .nuget.props and .nuget.targets files in the project directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I have found a fix, but questions remain. It's not clear to me whether this is a Xamarin Forms issue, a TeamCity issue or a NuGet issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to fix the problem, but it's not clear to me why it would manifest in the way it has -- locally and even when I RDP onto the build agent, it builds without trouble, but when I run the build agent from the TeamCity console I hit these compilation errors.

One of my dependencies is a NuGet package, which itself has a dependency on Xamarin Forms. Fortunately, I own that NuGet package, and was able to upgrade its Xamarin Forms version to the latest available package. If I didn't own that package I would be completely stuck though -- so this is only a partial solution.

Comment: this was quiet helpful for me . i would like to add a couple of additional notes though.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer was quite helpful for me . I would like to add a couple of additional notes though. I was facing this issue when I was using Xamarin Forms 3+ and my local build was being really inconsistent with the same error  "Xamarin.Forms tasks do not match targets. Please ensure that all projects reference the same version of Xamarin.Forms, and if the error persists, please restart the IDE.". Then I cleared my local NuGet cache and rebuilt the project and saw that there were other NuGet package versions being pulled for Xamarin Forms when I did a NuGet restore. I then reversed the ordering of the NuGet packages starting with Xamarin Forms and it all worked fine.

Comment: It's amazing how many hoops you need to jump through to get Xamarin working sometimes. Thanks for the info.