# System references have yellow triangle Xamarin.Forms iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I "migrated" from packages.config to PackageReference in my XF iOS project and migrated my PCL projects to .NET Standard targeting 1.4.  Now, my iOS project is giving me a bunch of errors like

```
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
```

for basically any system type.  Looking at the references I see System, System.Core and System.Xml all have the yellow triangle.

[image]

I have removed ALL NuGet packages and re-installed them.

I am using: 
VS 2017 15.7.1
Xamarin 4.10.0.442
Xamarin.iOS 11.10.1.177
Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0.44617
XCode 9.3.1

Any help is always appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if you migrated to `.Net Standard` [following this steps](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/116432/change-upgrade-from-pcl-to-net-standard), but I'm sure it's not a trivial job. I've heard about a lot of problems of this nature after try to do that.

Comment: [Try this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222209/opening-solution-using-visual-studio-2017/50224100#50224100), check for duplicated nuget references, **delete** and **restore** your nuget packages, change some setting of your ios project, save it (to force a `.csproj` update) and try build again. It's more about faith than science

Comment: Which build tool are you using ? Is it VS for mac ?

Comment: I'm using VS for windows, I have VS for Mac installed on the build machine and it's build tool is set to MSBuild not Xamarin Build.

Comment: are you solve this problem? i have it too

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual studio for Mac, The build tool might create issues. Change it to MSbuild for Mac and let us know if it resolves the issue.
[image]

Comment: I’m using Visual Studio on Windows 10 pro, obviously the build for iOS is passed off to the Mac.  I do have VS for Mac installed, but I thought the build was passed to Xcode?

Comment: Does all references are displaying error ? Whats the Xamarin.IOS nuget package version on the solution ?

Comment: I am using Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0.446417, and the only references displaying the error are System, System.Core and System.xml.  I've updated the original question with a snapshot of the references.